# Facebook SDK not working with PhoneGap 3.1 build

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing a HTML 5, CSS 3, jQuery Mobile app and am using PhoneGap Build to generate iOS and eventually Android builds.  I'm trying to integrate Facebook JS SDK into my app.  I can get Facebook login to work when running my app in a browser.  However, after running a zip of my app through build.phonegap.com I'm not able to login using Facebook.  All of the examples I've found online shows using XCode for integrating Facebook.  I'm not using XCode, just creating a HTML 5 app and running it through phonegap build.  Is XCode necessary?

In my config.xml, I'm including the following:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="[XXXXXX]" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="[APP NAME HERE]" />
</gap:plugin>
```

Is PhoneGap's Facebook connect needed if I'm also loading Facebook JavaScript SDK Asynchronously?

Here's my code for initializing facebook:

```
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() 
        {
            ApplicationUtils.CheckConnection();

            FB.init
            ({
                appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
                oauth : true ,// enable OAuth 2.0           
                nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
                useCachedDialogs: false
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
            {
                // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
                if (response.status === 'connected') 
                {
                    alert('connected to facebook!');
                } 
                else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
                {
                    alert('not authorized for facebook!');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert('not logged in to facebook!');
                }
            });
        });
```

When I run my app and go to the login page, the login button does not show even though I'm logged into Facebook.  I never get any of the alerts either.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.